# How to grep through HTML using GNU grep 2.12 and bash 4.2.37?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I've never used grep to parse HTML files, and am having the following problem:

```
grep -Po "(?s)(<h2>.+?<!-- /endcontent -->)" input.html > output.html
-bash: !--: event not found
```

I also tried…

```
grep -Po "(?s)(<h2>.+?\<!-- \/endcontent --\>)" input.html > output.html
```

… to no avail.

Is there a way to get grep/bash to parse HTML files, or is there another application I should use?

Thank you.

---

Edit: It looks like there is a trick between the shell and grep. Searching for the exact string "test" works, while neither "t.st" nor 't.st' works. Anybody knows why?

---

Edit: It's the "-P" option that breaks the regex, for some reason.

---

Edit: Yes, the "-P" option requires doubling the dot character that stands for any character. Weird.

```
grep -Po 't..st' input > output
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes `'` instead, like this:

```
grep -Po '(?s)(<h2>.+?<!-- /endcontent -->)' input.html > output.html
```

Grep acts differently when things are double-quoted.

Comment: Thanks. I experience weird behavior, with a single- or a double-quote: "test" and 'test' are OK, while "t.st" and 't.st' aren't. I'll read up on grep to understand how to use it correctly.